# What does 'Building new PostgreSQL source with configure flags mean' from the PGSQL Docs?

Tags: postgresql

I've been tasked with upgrading our Postgresql database to 9.4 and I'm following the instructions found on the documentation found here:

[Upgrading Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgupgrade.html)

The second step for upgrading to 9.4 says this:

```
For source installs, build the new version

Build the new PostgreSQL source with configure flags that are compatible    
with the old cluster. pg_upgrade will check pg_controldata to make sure all settings 
are compatible before starting the upgrade.
```

I rarely have to go into the internals of PGSQL and I'm not sure what is meant by the term 'configure flags'. Is this a specfic term in reference to PGSQL or does this refer tot he command line options at the top of the documentation page? In fact, do I even need to do this? The very nex st sentence says that pg_ugprade will do it for me. I'm upgrading our database that has a lot of sensitive data and I need to get this right. Obviously I have a sandbox though to play with but if someone can help me understand what that means, I'd appreciate it. I've come to find that dealing with PGSQL can be frustrating as hell. Thanks.

Comment: You should read that as: `[with configure flags that are compatible with the old cluster]` BTW: why do you build from source? (There is nothing wrong with that, but it might be more difficult for beginners) `Configure flags` are the options that you add to the `./configure` command before compiling. please check the README and/or INSTALL in the source directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply wildplasser. I'll check those files that you specified. I interpreted 'Build the new Postgresql' as 'apt install postgresql-9.4'. I didn't think that meant having to do that task manually or whatever 'build the new version' means.

Comment: `apt-get install ...` installs the binaries. So you should ignore the part about installing from source. (and *assume* that these binaries were created with the same or compatible flags the old ones)

Comment: Most of the PostgreSQL documentation - unfortunately - assumes you've installed from source code by compiling yourself.